# Add simple open/close animation to element.classList.toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have integrated a simple JS function to show/hide a long description. What I do not want to succeed is that the opening and closing of the DIV is animated. CSS does not allow the transition to display (to my knowledge), so the animation should be solved by JavaScript - which I do not get executable. Does anyone have a tip for me? Google has not helped me so far unfortunately ...

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("description");
  element.classList.toggle("desvisible");
}
```

```css
#description { display: none; }
#description.desvisible { display: block; }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show more Details</button>
<div id="description">Here a long description.</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean to tag [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info)?  In which case [`$("#description").slideToggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Comment: It's not clear exactly what "animation" you're after, but there are [plenty of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+fade+in+out) already in SO for css animations

Comment: Hm, no, that doesn't work. The div container has an arbitrary height and should disappear completely if the class is not set. Therefore the container gets the display: none; - if the class is set, it is display: block. This works and elements below it will be moved further down. Only the display-parameters are not animatable by a transition. The animation should show the connector when the class is set and hide it completely when it is not there. As I said, that works quite well so far. The only thing missing is a smooth transition of the function.

Comment: I made a short codepen for visualization: https://codepen.io/Rothwild/pen/mdOOvyb

Comment: Css wont' allow a "display" transition (from none to block) but there's many ways to do as you wish without javascript. Like this: https://codepen.io/alvaro-menendez/pen/rNWWPmr

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work, even if it's a very good idea. Because the div is displayed but still has a height that I can't get rid of. In addition, the container now has a max-height that I can't use, because different amounts of content are available on different pages. :(